# PHP - Iterator hiding a map, what should `valid` do?

Tags: php

```
class Map implements \ArrayAccess, \iterator {
    private $map;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->map = array();
    }

    /* Iterator interface:
     *  abstract public mixed current ( void )
     *  abstract public scalar key ( void )
     *  abstract public void next ( void )
     *  abstract public void rewind ( void )
     *  abstract public boolean valid ( void )
     */
    public function current() {
        return \current($this->map);
    }
    public function key() {
        return \key($this->map);
    }
    public function next() {
        \next($this->map);
    }
    public function rewind() {
        \reset($this->map);
    }
    public function valid() {
        //What should go here?
    }
/*so on*/
```

To be able to `foreach` over this structure I have to implement the interface noted in the code comments. All of them except `valid` have obvious functions I can use to apply them to the `map` I am encapsulating.

The example used on the `Iterator` page is that of a "list type" which simply keeps a count of how far along it is in the array.

What should I use as my implementation for `valid`?

Comment: A side note: you don't need to instantiate an array property in the constructor, just declare it with `private $map = array()`. This helps some IDEs to understand what type `$map` is. Regards

Comment: @Voitcus eclipse is pretty good anyway. Also in any event the `/** */` style comments Doxygen picks up with `@var` help with types - Which eclipse also uses. There's a lot of PHP I don't embrace :P Keeping things in ctors is one. Thanks though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just answered my question.

I was finding links to the documentation and I wondered "maybe `key`..."

A null key makes no sense (EVEN for PHP) and it uses that for the `[]` append operator and stuff. So if `key` returns null, it is out of bounds.

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.key.php

Comment: Thanks for this question and answer, I've spent some time too. I would suggest you directly insert in the answer `public function valid(){ return !is_null(key());}`. You may also accept your own answer.

Comment: I'm glad it helped someone! It justifies me clicking "add own answer" rather than the back button! @Voitcus

Comment: I have also found [this comment](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php#90715), in case you are interested